# Where can I get the basic concepts of java beans? 

Tags: java, javabeans

Please suggest a tutorial about java beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Trails: JavaBeans tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively [The JavaBeans Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/).